# Cannot join wireless networks on Ubuntu 14.10. Macbook pro 7.1

Tags: wireless, broadcom, macbook

I've got an Ubuntu 14.10 live usb I'm fiddling with. At some point in the 12.xx cycle my wifi started getting funky in Ubuntu, and it's never recovered.

I've got a mid-2010 Macbook pro (7.1) using the b43 open source driver.
With the STA proprietary driver I don't list any networks, with b43 I can at least see what's around me. HOWEVER I can't join any of them. I live in military housing and the only network available to me is an open network that is mac-filtered via a logon after joining, I don't know if I can for some reason join encrypted networks. Does anyone have any debugging suggestions? I'd love to start using Ubuntu again.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about ubuntu as I am trying it I installed it on my lenovo dual boot with windows and had the same issue. I did some search and fixed it by using the b43 answer i forgot all details how. but i did install ubuntu again in my other presario old laptop dual boot aswell and had the same problem. here what solved the issue for me: you have to install the b43 driver and remove the STA driver to make your wireless detected and connect wirelessely.

To install the b43 drivers
1. sudo apt-get firmware-b43-installer

To remove the STA drivers
2. sudo apt get remove bcmwl-kernel-source

Restart your computer.

It worked for me, and hope it will help others.. sorry if its not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but as I stated in the OP I already have the b43 drivers installed, and the STA driver removed.